# set image from device to ImageView not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, imageview

I am trying to upload the image to cloud fire storage, the code is in below:

```
Uri userImagePath;
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
StorageReference storageReference = storage.getReference("UserImages");

private void pickImage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == 1 && requestCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData()!=null){
            userImagePath = data.getData();
            userImage.setImageURI(userImagePath);
        }
    }
```

**Problem is this when running the app image is not set to the imageview.** image picker is open and allows to select image but it doesn't show in imageview.
There is no error showing
but in logcat shows like this:

```
2021-02-04 03:07:12.690 22126-23476/com.example.abcd D/FA: Application going to the background
2021-02-04 03:07:14.419 22126-22126/com.example.abcd D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=64
2021-02-04 03:07:19.339 22126-23476/com.example.abcd V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

I did **Individate Caches/Restart** also, and I **uninstall .the app and reinstall again.** But the problem still has. Selected image not showing in imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the bitmap from the picked up image steam as following:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1 && requestCode == RESULT_OK && data.getData()!=null){
        userImagePath = data.getData();
        
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(userImagePath);  // to read image data

            // get a bitmap from a stream
            Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            userImage.setImageBitmap(image);


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("LOG_TAG", e.getMessage());
        }

   }
}
```